# Should I be worried about the pixelation in my photo?

Tags: sensor, noise, nikon-d3200

I took a photo of a lake and while editing it I found that the image actually had sensors pixel view all over the picture.
Is this something I should worry about?

Here in my photo, Pixels of the sensor are visible, where as noise appears to be like dark spots in the image(grain).

Attaching pic for reference.[image: sensor pixels visible in photo]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reduce the noise in this image / prevent noise in future images?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20077/how-do-i-reduce-the-noise-in-this-image-prevent-noise-in-future-images)

Comment: As per my understanding, noise is something which gets introduced due to low light condition and high ISO. In my scenario, The pixels of the sensors itself are visible in the darker areas of the photo. The trees in the background and their reflection.

Comment: What do you mean by "the pixels of the sensor itself"? If you zoom in far enough you can always see the pixels of an image as recorded by the photosites on the sensor. The entire image is literally made up of the pixels of the sensor itself.

Comment: This is not a zoomed in image or cropped image. Its the original(file format RAW). Instead of an image, Its just black squares. I expect it to be clear black.

Comment: Is this a raw image that hasn't been demosaiced and was simply converted to JPEG?

Comment: @tushar It is a JPEG image. It may be that you didn't do any editing before converting the raw file to JPEG, but at the very least the application you used did apply a default set of settings to the raw file to produce this jpeg.

Comment: As to whether you should be worried or not about the appearance of the image is an opinion based question that only you can answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I be worried about the pixelation in my photo?

Not in this case, because what you are describing is noise. That is a totally diferent issue than pixelation.

Pixelation is when you rescale an image too much that the individual pixels shows.

> Should I be worried about **noise** in my photo?

As you said, noise is most apparent in low light scenarios. Period. Actually, all images have noise, but you see it more clearly on the dark part of the photo.

This dark part of the photo can be on any photo, but on a dark scene, normally you need to blow the dark zones so the noise is visible.

Shooting in raw gives you a little more freedom to control it. You can also apply some filters to reduce it.

Comment: Banding caused by reduction in color depth (or in the case of monochrome images, tonal depth) can cause a blocky look that some people refer to as pixelation. In such a case the "pixelized" blocks are considerably larger than the size of individual pixels in the image.

Comment: Banding, noise, compression artifacts, pixelation, etc. They are diferent "sickness" of a photo. If they are identified correctly its easier to find a solution.

Comment: @MichaelClarkThank you for the information shared.

Answer (score 0):

The picture definitely has a lot of grain (noise) which is not something to be confused with pixelation. Increasing the DPI (scaling) leads to pixelated  windows and images. 
Coming to your picture again, it looks really soft around the edges and the background behind the tree has a lot of noise. If you clicked RAW, then you can definitely recover some details using processing tools. For JPEG, there is not much that can be done to an image.